# How to equally divide time of upload progress bar in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

js and JavaScript what I am trying to is use Axios `onUploadProgress`  function in such a way that it start from 1% and goes all the way to 100 percent .

Here is my code :

```
onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
  let percentage=(progressEvent.loaded * 100/ (progressEvent.total + 10000000)) ;
  percentage=parseInt(Math.round(percentage));
  this.uploadPercentage[progress_index] = percentage;      
}.bind(this)
```

It start from 1 % then move to 2 % and then quickly move towards 100 % what I am trying to achieve is it goes from 1 % and then to 2 % and then it moves to the 3 % and then goes on till the 100% percent I have no clue how I can achieve this if any one can help I will be thank full

Comment: Why the `+ 10000000`? Also, why `parseInt` after `Math.round()`?

Comment: + 10000000 increases the time like if i don't use it quickly make it 100% for delay i am using

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ProgressEvent documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent):

- `total` is a number representing the total amount of work to be done.
- `loaded` is a number representing amount of work that is completed.

So `loaded/total` gives you a ratio between 0 and 1 (i.e. 0.5 when you are half done). You can get it to percentages by multiplying with 100, i.e. `100 * loaded/total`.

But if you add 10M to total, your ratio will not reach 1. Assume `total` is 2000 and we are half done, so `loaded` is 1000. The result should be 0.5, but with your addition, it is actually 0.5 * 10^-7 (0,00000005).

Long story short, drop the +10M.